# Create one keybord shortcut for 2 objects in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

How can i create for "Ctrl+C" bindings for 2 objects: self.table, self.editor

I have:

```
shortcut = QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+C"), self.table, None, self.copyTable)
shortcut2 = QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+C"), self.editor, None, self.copyText)
```

This works, but is toogled. If i have focus on self.editor and for the first time i press "Ctrl+C it does self.copyTable, the second time is does self.copyText.

What am i doing wrong? :P

I did find a workaround where i create a QAction which checks which object has focus and triggers the wanted action. But i would rather have it per object.

Edit (a working example):

```
shortcut = QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+C"), self, self.copytoclipbord)
shortcut.setContext(QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut)
```

Comment: You may pass `context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut` argument to `QShortcut` init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the correct context for short cuts: by default they are window-"global", you probably want them to be widget-"local".  See [setShortcutContext](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qaction.html#shortcutContext-prop).

Answer (score 3):

i did that already here and it worked fine ^_^. very simple idea .

> just make one shortcut and one slot.

```
QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+C"), self, None, self.copyFunction)
```

and inside copyFunction check the focus , like so :

```
def copyFunction(self):
    if self.table.hasFocus:
        self.copyTable()
    elif self.editor.hasFocus:
        self.copyEditor()
```